# Is it possible to execute the test using Robotium without PC. Just my Android device only

Tags: android, robotium

Can I execute my test without using command line or not connected to PC? Just using only my Android device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, It is possible 
Install DevTools App [more details here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-devtools.html)

After installing the test apk open "devTools" -> Instrumentaion and select "android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner' .